# No compile check for generics in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Given the following code:

```
interface Contract<T> {
}

class Deal<D> implements Contract<D> {
}

class Agreement<A> implements Contract<A> {
}
```

I would have expected this not to compile:

```
let deal:Contract<number> = new Deal<number>()
let agreement:Contract<string> = new Agreement<string>()

// expects this to not compile
agreement = deal;
```

or this

```
let deal:Deal<number> = new Deal<number>()
let agreement:Agreement<string> = new Agreement<string>()

// expects this to not compile
agreement = deal;
```

But they both compile!

Here is a playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=17&ssc=18&pln=17&pc=26#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHtxUWAPAFQD5kBvAKAF8yyEAbOAZweQBEI5bcXjgBbAB1oReEcMwxYcXYuSo16TZAEEA5lAjDReJTwFCRYtJjDYE2mZWpCwyACbtaALgkmpIAK68ARtGIBeZBAIAHdWB1wPb18ACgBKMmtkODUNAzBnY1M8BhNQFX9AkOUUzXBcHKg8wjjqAHpa5AgAD34IM2YwAAtgDvRA9BsEdAFgITJk9VKbAPsOAG46hsTZpzYOCM8fKAKg0LXOSK3q%20PrkRInUrUdVSbTy3JB85ADd4tute8rH48XkU%20bWu1kF0esC%20uBkEMRmNThcps87A45kA)

I would have expected that a `GenericOf<A>` is not the same as `Genericof<B>` and the compiler should not allow assigning one to the other. What am I missing here?

Comment: They are all structurally equivalent, since there is no implementation detail that would differ based on generics. [If they do change, they aren't assignable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHtxUWAPAFQD5kBvAKGUuRmAgBsATAfgC58yBfMshOuAZ37IAIhDh1cw4sAC2ABzoQZEcEIxYck4uSrVajViM7deAoQEEA5lAhKVec9PmLlqtJjDYED7RSo16ZhZkc2MyRTBkBjE6FnVPTRAAVxkAI2hiAF5kEAgAdxEY3GS0jIAKAEpwiEi4a1tXMDiPLzx+T1BLLJz8kPq7cFx2qE7CSu4AegnkCAAPOQhvITAAC2Bl9Bz0SIR0eWBFMjqbAcjs6PEAbknpiKiYllFxYpT0qG7cgqeJErexqqmyDuxwa9hYVhOjSGHRAXWQ2U+fUh9mhI1h-xuyEBcwWS2Qq3W+M24GQu32h0BINO8PuVyAA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TypeScript, type parameters only affect the resulting type when consumed as part of the type of a member. See [the relevant documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#generics) for more details.

If you actually *use* the generic, you do get exactly the error you are expecting:

```js
interface Contract<T> {
    log: (value: T) => void
}

class Deal<D> implements Contract<D> {
    log(value: D) {
        console.log(value)
    }
}

class Agreement<A> implements Contract<A> {
    log(value: A) {
        console.log(value)
    }
}

let deal: Contract<number> = new Deal<number>()
let agreement: Contract<string> = new Agreement<string>()

agreement = deal;
// Error: Type 'Contract<number>' is not assignable to type 'Contract<string>'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Comment: "*While I haven't found a authoritative source for this (yet),*" [Type Compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) explicitly states that TS checks if the structure is the same.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks, I'll edit it into my answer if you don't mind!